# How to create a Default, Custom Styled Spinner

Tags: android

I am trying create my custom Style spinner with help of [this](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/) site. But the changes no appear. I did exactly like shown in that site. But I don't know understand what should I do to see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this
create progress.xml in drawable folder with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" 
   android:drawable="@drawable/slider_back" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
  <clip android:drawable="@drawable/colorbar" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

create  thumb.xml in drawable folder with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb" />
</selector>
```

and this is the seekbar xml code in layout

```
<SeekBar                    
    android:id="@+id/frequency_slider"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:max="9"
    android:thumbOffset="0px"
    android:progress="0"                 
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>
```

add the required images for seek bar (for thumb and back ground image)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial says "Once you’ve created the themes, make sure you reference them from your applications manifest file."
Have you done that?

Comment: I tryed this <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/SpinnerSelector">

Comment: That's ok, but I found something, that's not in the tutorial. In the themes.xml the <style> tags must between <resources> tag. Like <resources> <style>...</style> <style>...</style> </resources>.

Comment: and of course themes.xml starts with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>